# How to set a div next to an image and center it vertically?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I want to know how to place an image next to a div and center the div (progress bar) vertically?

What I want to do:

[image]
Here is my code for the progress bar:

```
<div class="progressbar">
  <div class="skill"><span>HTML 5</span></div>
</div>

.progressbar {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 200px;
  }

.progressbar > div {
    background-color: #FDEE18;
    width: 175px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .skill span {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `display: table` and `display:table-cell;` like this :

> CSS

```
img { height: 60px;  display: table-cell;  }
#container { display: table;}
.container-progress { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;}
```

> HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" alt="">
  <div class="container-progress">
    <div class="progressbar">
      <div class="skill"><span>HTML 5</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/atr9e800/3/)

Comment: I have one more question, how can I set more progress bars with different content and img? 

Something like this: http://prntscr.com/ate5or

Comment: Yeah something like this. 
So if i have for example 10 progress bars, then I just have to copy the html and css over and over? Is there maybe an easier way to do it, if not is it a problem to have one bloc of code 10 times with just the classname different? Thank you

Comment: You can use a dymanic language such as PHP to generate the HTML through a loop, or use javascript to append a content in a loop too.

Comment: Hmm okay I understand, Thanks again for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a table for both elements:

```html
    <table>
      <tr align="center">
        <td align="center">
          <div>
            <img src="http://images3.moneysavingexpert.com/images/small-claims-court.png">
          <div>
        </td>
        <td allign="center">
          <div>
            <img src="http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/pure-css3-progress-bar.jpg">
          <div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```